# $\exists n\in\mathbb{Z}$, $n>2003$ s.t. in sequence ${n\choose 0},{n\choose 1},{n\choose 2},..., {n\choose 2003}$ all terms divide all succeeding ones

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients, divisibility

Prove that there exists an integer $n>2003$ that in the sequence $${n\choose 0}, {n\choose 1}, {n\choose 2}, ..., {n\choose 2003}$$ every term divides every succeeding term. That is $$\\ {n\choose i} | {n\choose i+1},{n\choose i+2},...,{n\choose 2003}$$
Could anyone verify my proof?
My approach was to plug in some values and I deduced that a number $(1)N = lcm(1,2,3,...,2003)-1$ is likely to satisfy the given statement. And for the proof lets consider $$\\ \frac{N\choose i+1}{N\choose i} = \frac{N(N-1)...(N-i+1)(N-i)}{(i+1)!}\cdot\frac{i!}{N(N-1)...(N-i+1)}=\frac{N-i} {i+1}$$ and considering both $0\le i< i+1\le2003$ and $(1)$ we get that $i+1|N+1$ and hence $i+1|N+1-(i+1)=N-i$  hence N satisfies the condition.

Comment: Yes, this works. Any multiple of the LCM can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your proof works. Let me clarify it a bit here:

Let $n$ be an integer such that for every integer $i$ with $0\leq i\leq2002$, the ratio between $\tbinom{n}{i+1}$ and $\tbinom{n}{i}$ is an integer. This ratio is
$$\frac{\binom{n}{i+1}}{\binom{n}{i}}=\frac{i!(n-i)!}{(i+1)!(n-i-1)!}=\frac{n-i}{i+1}.$$
As you note, this is an integer if and only if
$$\frac{n-1}{i+1}+1=\frac{n+1}{i+1},$$
is an integer, and so the integers $n$ that work are precisely the integers of the form
$$n=-1+k\cdot\operatorname{lcm}(1,\ldots,2003),$$
for any integer $k\geq1$.